# Is there any way to set some Config like dontWaitForChildProcessOutput= true for the JavaExec task

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, javaexec-gradle-plugin

Is there any way to set some Config like

```
 dontWaitForChildProcessOutput= true
```

on my JavaExec task. So that the Task gets completed without waiting for the Child process .
There is something called ignoreExitValue but it doesnot server the purpose

Help Please